# Protocol fault (no status) or Device not found error when sideloading

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, motorola-moto-g, side-loading

I'm using the Moto G 1st gen, mfastboot and Cyanogenmod. I've turned off MTP, enabled usb debugging and have set the android device to use the motorola adb interface in device manager.

If i kill the adb.exe in task manager, i eliminate the protocol error but get "not found" instead.

I'm currently installing the android sdk in order to apply [this](http://jodieorourke.com/view.php?id=190&blog=news). Please say if you know a better way.